# getting form data before posting to server extjs 6, and sencha touch 2.4

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6

Before submitting my form data to server, I want it to maniplate it a little bit 
i have written `beforerequest` method for all the requests
now how do i get the actual form data from the before request
this is my code:

```
Ext.define('test.view.BaseUrl', {
singleton : true,

constructor : function(config) {
    Ext.Ajax.on('beforerequest', this.onBeforeRequest, this);
},

onBeforeRequest : function(connection, options) {
    console.log(connection);
    console.log(options);
    // How can i get the post data here
    // like id = 1, name = 'something'
}
});
```

[image]

Comment: beforerequest event gives us 3 arguments:  conn , request, eOpts.Here you can manipulate the request object as you want.Currently options is your 2nd parameter in which you will get the actual request.Check it and reply.

Comment: how do i get the actual request from options, like the acutal xtype: 'textfield' vlaues etc

Comment: will it be possible for you to simulate this in some fiddle , there it can be quickly solved.

Comment: added an image, first and second argument console

Comment: Please give actual json of the "data" of second parameter.Your form data is present over there.

Comment: All data is present in "data" section of second argument.